# Useful fact on order of U-groups of prime powers

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

The U-group $U\left ( n \right )$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is the set of all elements less than n and relatively prime to n.

If n is an odd prime and m is any positive integer, are there any common useful fact about the order of the U-group,

$\left | U\left ( p^{m} \right ) \right |$?

Comment: The order is given by the Euler phi-function, which see.

Comment: Thank you very much Gerry

Answer (score 2):

There are $p^m$ integers up to $p^m$. Exactly one in every $p$ is divisible by $p$, and so there are $p^{m-1}$ elements up to $p^m$ divisible by $p$. Thus there are $p^m - p^{m-1}$ elements up to $p^m$ which are not divisible by $p$, and therefore are relatively prime to $p^m$.

Stated differently, this can be written as $|U(p^m)| = \varphi(p^m) = p^m - p^{m-1} $, where $\varphi$ is the Euler phi function.

Comment: This is definitely going into my book of useful fact.